# Decoding Training Examples

Tags: tensorflow

I am using a ddsm dataset to make a CNN, and the owner of the dataset gave some code to decode the training examples, but I can't figure out what first part of the code is actually doing. Still learning. 
For reference: https://www.kaggle.com/skooch/ddsm-mammography/home

The code:  features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'label_normal': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })